# GSuite API service account - verifying impersonated user credentials through API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

We are integrating Google Calendar with our room booking system. Users in GSuite domain should login on our reservation screen and book a room. So far I made use of an service account with domain wide delegation to impersonate the users (the `setSubject()` method, passing the e-mail address of the impersonated user). Everything works, although this way we cannot verify if the user we want to impersonate is logged in successfully or not, the event will be just created with him as the organizer, because setSubject() only requires the email to work properly.
In IBM Domino, when using an Java XPage I was able to compare passwords of the user, not in plain text but there was a function which compared plain text with user's hashed password and returned true if they were equal.
As I see Google doesn't have such a thing if I'm right. How could I check if the user can successfully log in programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform actions in Google Calendar on behalf of a currently logged-in user from a web browser, you might want to use [OAuth2 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) instead of using a service account with impersonation.